# How to count lines of text in Cell if Interop.Word.Cell.WordWrap is true

Tags: interop, ms-word, word-wrap

In Microsoft Word if Cell.WordWrap = true; and Microsoft Word wraps text to multiple lines.

How to count lines of text in that cell ?

Answer (score 0):

Unsure as to whether it is possible, but I would guess that you could search the contents for `'\r\n'` (CRLF) and count these to indicate how many lines.

Comment: I'm don't think that in wrapped text adds a '\r\n'